# ShotGun Spread unity 3d FPS shooter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an fps game and I have an inventory system implemented. However when I add the shotgun and then shoot it the bullets do spread but they spread on the horizontal axis and it looks kinda odd. Can some one walk me through how to implement proper shooting with bullet spread.
Here is what I have so far. another issue with that is that when the player is looking left the bullets would not spread but instead they would go in line with each other.

```
    public int BulletsShot; // Total bullets show per Shot of the gun
    public float BulletsSpread; // Degrees (0-360) to spread the Bullets
    public GameObject BulletTemplate; // Bullet to fire

    public void Fire()
    {
        float TotalSpread = BulletsSpread / BulletsShot;
        for (int i = 0; i < BulletsShot; i++)
        {
            // Calculate angle of this bullet
            float spreadA = TotalSpread * (i + 1);
            float spreadB = BulletsSpread / 2.0f;
            float spread = spreadB - spreadA + TotalSpread / 2;
            float angle = cam.transform.eulerAngles.y;

            // Create rotation of bullet
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, spread + angle, 0));

            // Create bullet
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(BulletTemplate, tip.position, tip.rotation);
            bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * pelletFireVel);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe with a particle system, tweaking the values to be the shotgun cone you want, and registering the collisions of the particles shooted

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Camera.ScreenPointToRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html)

I would also recommend you do the bullet spread in world space coordinates, as screen space will be screen size-dependent.

#### Code Example:

```
void SpreadShots(Vector3 screenPos)
{
    int shots = 4;
    float spread = 1f;

    Camera cam = Camera.main;

    for (int i = 0; i < shots; i++)
    {
        Vector3 tapWorldPos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPos);

        Vector3 spreadWorldPos = Random.insideUnitCircle * spread;

        Vector3 finalScreenPos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(tapWorldPos + spreadWorldPos);

        Ray shootRay = cam.ScreenPointToRay(screenPos);

        // Create projectile and shoot it towards shootRay.direction
    }
}
```